# Is returning promise form angular service bad?

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise, angular-2+, rxjs

What is the problem when I return a promise from `angular service` instead of Observable?
If it's a matter of any manipulation or side-effect, that I can easily do inside angular service itself. Then why I shouldn't return a promise over observable?

**Here's my code for service class**

```
public async getCountriesAsync(filter: PaginateFilter): Promise<Paginate<IdNameTypeModel>> {
return await this.http.get<Paginate<IdNameTypeModel>>(`/api/{version}/Types/{lang}/Countries${filter.url()}`)
  .pipe(map(response => {
    return response == null ? new Paginate<IdNameTypeModel>() : response;
  })).toPromise();   
}
```

**Using inside component**

```
async loadCountries() {
  const filter = new PaginateFilter(this.data.pageIndex, this.data.pageSize);
  this.countries = await this.dldTypesService.getCountriesAsync(filter);
}
```

Comment: On a side note, always use triple equality -> `response == null` will be `true` if `response = undefined` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Per se returning a promise from an Angular Service is not bad, however there are numerous things in Angular world that are heavily based on Observables:

- <del>usually you will likely change the *change detection* to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your components and this will most likely be easier with Angular's `async` pipe</del> **not a problem**, because `async` also supports Promises.
- if you use your services for any kind of state and if your are using *NgRx* for effectively managing it, you'll be using `@Effects`that are basically a lot of RxJs magic and thus it might be easier to use *Observables* in the first place.
- composing services for *Guards* is easier with Observables

Having that said, I agree with you, that typical REST services are *fire and forget* and thus IMO do not fit really into `Observables` well which are meant to be constant sources of events.

It is all about composition, Observables allow better composition for **multiple** async operations that need to be **composed**, whereas Promises can be nowadays used pretty easy with `async/await` for **singular, isolated** operations.

In the end, I'd advise to stick with the same convention throughout your whole app - **either** have all services return *Promises* and convert them to *Observables* when needed **or** always use *Observables*. I assume a lot of examples are using Observables because for non-trivial apps you end up needing better composition options than with pure Promises.